# Why does `cat \` return a prompt?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, sh, cat

When I run `cat \` in my terminal, it returns a newline and a prompt 

`>`

where I can input a filename to be printed.

Echo also does this, so it seems like a Unix thing. Why does this happen, and what does this teach me about Unix in general?

I've read the respective man pages, but I don't see anything. Googling has shown me that trailing backslashes must be escaped because of shell interpretations, but not what those shell interpretations are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's shell syntax. The `\` in front of a newline (pressing enter) escapes that newline:

From `man bash`:

> A  non-quoted backslash (\) is the escape character.  It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception of new‐line.  If a newline pair appears, and the backslash is not itself quoted, the newline is treated as a  line  continuation  (that  is,  it  is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).

or in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_01):

> A backslash that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a newline. If a newline follows the backslash, the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The backslash and newlines shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens. Since the escaped newline is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator.

That means entering the command line hasn't completed and the shell continues to read it in the next line, displaying the `>` prompt.

Btw, the `>` can be configured via the `PS2` environment variable. Try:

```
$ PS2='(continue cmdline) ... '
$ cat \
```

Also the behaviour of PS2 is specified in POSIX:

> **PS2**
>       Each time the user enters a newline prior to completing a command line in an interactive shell, the value of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written to standard error. The default value is "> "

Comment: Was just about to research that :) ... I'm pretty sure about the line continuation but not about `PS2`. Give me a minute.

Comment: Oh, I see you found it :)

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ PS2='(continue cmdline) ... '
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat \
(continue cmdline) ... 
 PS2 works for me. :) yep

Comment: ok! btw, the standard for the posix compatible shell command language (what /bin/sh is supposed to provide on UNIX) can be found here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Comment: That is a nice complete answer

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

A backslash escapes the character that follows after, in this case the linefeed character (which is inserted when you press return). It allows you to wrap overly long lines onto multiple lines for better readability, e.g.

```
echo this is a very long sentence to be\
 printed to your terminal
```

is identical to

```
echo this is a very long sentence to be printed to your terminal
```